# Export HTML table to text or CSV file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a PHP search page which outputs results to an HTML table.  I am using a jQuery plugin to allow the columns to be sorted by clicking on the column headers.  I would like to allow users to download the search results to a TXT or CSV file, but I would like the sort order to be preserved.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Probably easiest to just call a service, passing in your sort order

Comment: yup, what jchapa is saying... `?sortOrder=asc&isExport=true`

Comment: But the sorting is done by javascript, not PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser side (javascript) can't generate downlodable files, so you need to generate it from server side (php in you case). You can keep track of the last **order** used with javascript and pass it forward to the PHP script to generate the file in the propper order

Comment: side note: you can generate a new tab (or window) with javascript with the content of the .csv file on it.  But this requires the user to copy & paste on his own.

Comment: I can get the sort order from Javascript, but how do I pass it to the PHP script?

Comment: do you have a "download" button or link?  execute a javascript call on it including `window.open('generateCSV.php?orderBy='+JsVarKeepingOrder)`

Answer (score 0):

That jquery plugin works by updating an element, probably a div with table.

Just get the div innerhtml and parse it with an regular expression.

in jquery that would be $(divname).html()

Comment: go with Luis Siquot answer is more complete than mine.

Answer (score -2):

This is a good jQuery plugin for working with tables:

http://www.datatables.net/

And you can use tabletools with datatables
http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/TableTools/index.html

Comment: It would seem he is using a sorting plugin. The datatables plugin has many more features and capabilities including sorting and exporting the table to csv. In addition they provide extensive documentation and examples to help them figure it out.